# Running a CMD command through python fails

Tags: python, windows, cmd, pcap

I'm using [SplitCap](https://www.netresec.com/?page=SplitCap) to split my pcaps into sessions. However, given that I have hundreds of them I want to write something to do it for me.

This CMD command works successfully.

```
G:\Program Files\Wireshark\PCAP>"G:\Program Files\Wireshark\SplitCap.exe" -r nonvpn-chat-aim-0.pcap -s session -o SplitPCAP
Splitting pcap file into seperate pcap files...
100%
Please wait while closing all file handles...
```

However, the exact same command fails in python:

```py
>>> arg
['G:/Program Files/Wireshark/SplitCap.exe', '-r', 'G:/Program Files/Wireshark/PCAP/nonvpn-chat-aim-0.pcap', '-s', 'session', '-o', 'SplitPCAP']
>>> subprocess.run(arg)
```

```
Splitting pcap file into seperate pcap files...
10%
���� ����� �����: System.NotSupportedException: ����� ����� ������ ���� �����.
   �-  System.Security.Permissions.FileIOPermission.EmulateFileIOPermissionChecks(String fullPath)
   �-  System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath, Boolean checkHost)
   �-  System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options)
```

I'm not sure how to proceed from here. This error seems to be in C# and looking inside `subprocess.py` hasn't been much help...

Comment: Are you running python from the same current working directory as you were when using your shell? i.e. `G:\Program Files\Wireshark\PCAP>`. Run in python  `import os; print(os.getcwd())`

Comment: Also might be a path issue. You're feeding in a unix style directory string, when in the command line app you're using the current working dir. Might be worth trying this arg instead: `r'G:\Program Files\Wireshark\PCAP\nonvpn-chat-aim-0.pcap'`

Comment: I'm not running from the same directory, and I tried doing this:
subprocess.run(arg, cwd="G:\....") without success.

Also, if you notice the error message - it says Splitting pcap file - which means the actual SplitCap.exe starts running, no?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that the file argument of SplitCap doesn't like paths the way I was using them. The solution was to change `subprocess.run(arg)` to `subprocess.run(arg, cwd="'G:/Program Files/Wireshark/SplitCap.exe'"` and then change `arg` to be:

`['G:/Program Files/Wireshark/SplitCap.exe', '-r', 'nonvpn-chat-aim-0.pcap', '-s', 'session', '-o', 'SplitPCAP']`

That is, change the part after -r to exclude the full path. (and also, changing `\` to `/`

Answer (score 0):

you can try os to excute cmd

```
os.system()
or
os.popen()
```

and the later one can get the return information with socket

Comment: This wasn't the problem. It turns out flakes was partly correct in that the issue was running it outside of the directory. I'll explain in an answer to myself.